# Is it possible to apply an apartment from boligforening in Denmark before arriving in the country?

Tags: housing, denmark

Has anyone had the experience of renting an apartment from a housing association (boligforening) in Denmark? It seems from my research that it may take years to get an apartment, although I also read that those with families are prioritized. I would like to know how quick it is to get an apartment from boligforening, and whether it is possible to apply one before arriving in Denmark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, technically it is possible to apply for an apartment from a housing association before arriving in the country. However, you will need to supply a local address, which could be a future address, if you have one, or your work address. It may take more than a month before you get your first offer, so indeed you can save a bit of time by applying earlier than your arrival in Denmark.